# @XmlElementRefs & @XmlElementRef annotations in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Can some please explain to me what do

```
@XmlElementRefs
```

and

```
@XmlElementRef
```

annotations mean in Java and what is their use..

> **EDIT:**
>   @skaffman

okay, suppose I have one such collection

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name="ElementA", type=ClassA),
    @XmlElementRef(name="ElementB", type=ClassB) }
)

List<Object> items;
```

Now how do I access every individual element of this list? Is the following code correct?

```
for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); ++j) {
    if (items.get(i).getClass().equals(ClassA)) {
        // perform ClassA specific processing:
    } else if (items.get(i).getClass().equals(ClassB)) {
        // perform ClassB specific processing:
    }
}
```

Is this correct approach? Is there a better way to perform each class specific processing? I mean is there a way to avoid those `if else` constructs?

Comment: You usually use this with polymorphism. ClassA and ClassB both extend ClassBase, so you don't need if/else to dispatch correctly the processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are used to annotate a collection which can contain various different types. The java binding for such a list is:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
   @XmlElementRef(name="ElementA", type=ClassA),
   @XmlElementRef(name="ElementB", type=ClassB)
})
List<Object> items
```

Here, `items` can contain an arbitrary mix of `ClassA` and `ClassB`, and since that can't be expressed in `List`'s type signature, it has to be expressed using annotations.

Comment: okay, suppose I have one such collection

@XmlElementRefs({
   @XmlElementRef(name="ElementA", type=ClassA),
   @XmlElementRef(name="ElementB", type=ClassB)
})
List<Object> items;

Now how do I access every individual element of this list? Is the following code correct?

for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); ++j) {
    if (items.get(i).getClass().equals(ClassA)) {
        // perform ClassA specific processing:
    } else if (items.get(i).getClass().equals(ClassB)) {
        // perform ClassB specific processing:
    } else 

}

Comment: I can't read that. Please add it your question (and format it properly.)

Comment: But the same also works with @XmlElements and @XmlElement, no?

Comment: how would you set ElementA or B to something?

Comment: Ok, I found difference: property annotated with @XmlElementRefs can contain descendant classes. <rs><a/><b/><suba/><subb/></rs> vs <es><a/><b/><suba xsi:type="suba" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><subb xsi:type="subb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></es>